# how to use regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex

How do I remove

```
<noindex><script>stuff</script></noindex>
```

in an SQL export using regex in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you explained a bit more. From your question it seems like you need something like this, but that's probably not what you intend.

```
<noindex><script>.+</script></noindex>
```

Comment: Hi ScriptWolf. `stuff` can be any JavaScript, so if your regex is for any multiple values, that's what I need.

Comment: Just keep in mind when using regex with tags, if they aren't VERY neat and tidy, you'll have a horrible time. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)